# How to add CMake INSTALL project automatically to build configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

I'm trying to deploy a couple of .ini files to the binary directory when compiling, using CMake. I did this through the following lines (typed by hand; feel free to edit if you find a typo)

```
FILE(GLOB INI_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../misc/*.ini")
INSTALL(FILES ${INI_FILES} CONFIGURATIONS Debug DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug)
INSTALL(FILES ${INI_FILES} CONFIGURATIONS Release DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release)
```

This properly generates an `INSTALL` project in my Visual Studio solution which works if 'compiled' manually. However, the project is not part of the Debug and Release build configurations of the Solution, meaning it won't be executed when compiling the solution. Is there a way to add the project manually to the build configurations in CMake?

Or is this not intended and I need to call CMake differently?

I'm Using CMake 3.0.2 with Visual Studio 2013.
I'm generating my Visual Studio solution like this:

```
"%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall" amd64
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a custom command to copy the .ini files before you build the project. Assuming your build target is named `my_target`, you can do something like this:

```
FILE(GLOB INI_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../misc/*.ini")
add_executable(my_target test.cpp)
foreach(FN ${INI_FILES})
    add_custom_command(TARGET my_target
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${FN}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
endforeach()
```

It basically uses cmake to copy the .ini files individually over to the build directory.

Comment: While this doesn't answer my actual questions, it provides a working solution for my initial intentions, therefore I'm accepting your answer.